# Making SELECT Query faster

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select

I've got a query in MySQL:

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE 
  (FIELD3 >= INT1 AND FIELD3 <= INT2) 
  AND FIELD2 IN (INTEGER_LIST)
```

Any ideas how to make this query faster? Both FIELD2 and FIELD3 are indexed. Even, when check on FIELD2 is removed, nothing happens related to performance.

Execution plan information:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: TABLE1
type: ref
possible_keys: FIELD2, FIELD3
key: FIELD2
ref: const
rows: 310000
Extra: using where
```

Comment: Show us your execution plan?

Comment: What do the indexes look like?

Comment: What's the INTEGER_LIST ?

Comment: i can't see anything wrong here when indexing is used correct! More often it's the MySQL Server Configuration that is to small. Show us your my.cnf please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  An index on `table1(field2, field3, field1)` should speed this query:

```
create index table1_field2_field3_field1 on table1(field2, field3, field1)
```

Comment: what if you have more fields in SELECT? Should you create then an index, ringing all of them?

Comment: @schmi . . . Probably not.  The key part is the first two columns.  The third seemed like a relatively low cost way of turning the index into a covering index for the query.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting up a compound index on (FIELD3, FIELD2) ? (see leftmost prefix issues in MySQL)

Setting an index really depends on the type of query you are expecting :

- possibly on both fields - separately (FIELD2 or FIELD3)
- always on these two fields together and in that order
- can be on (FIELD3. FIELD2) or (FIELD2, FIELD3)